# Loading csv files from a zip file in R results in no lines available in input error

Tags: r

not a question but a problem somebody else might stumble upon. I handle some data in csvs each week that is put into zip files to save space.
Usually I can easily read the csvs in the zip file with this code:

```
connections = unz(zip_path,csv_file)
DAT_r = read.csv2(connections, sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE,
                  encoding="latin1", fill=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
```

Today however I got the misleading error:

`Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote) : no lines available in input`

Answer (score 0):

After tedious checking of the csvs I realised the zip file was larger than usual. Indeed the size was too big to read in which spawned the error. Splitting the zip in two files resolved the error

Cheers